# Nested resources link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

sI'm having trouble linking to something like example.com/r/leagueoflegends/posts/1 . In my link i have

```
<%= link_to posts.title, category_post_path %>
```

but end up getting "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:category_id, :id]". I've tried other ways but still cant get it to work right.

My routes look like this

```
resources :categories, path: 'r', except: [:index] do
 resources :posts
end
```

Home controller

```
def index
 @posts = Post.all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should indicate to which category you're linking (not only post), so you should have:

```
<%= link_to post.title, [@category, post] %>
```

of course, you should have `@category` variable set, which should be in before filter in your controller:

```
before_filter :set_category
# ...
private

def set_category
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
end
```

and in your index action:

```
def index
  @posts = @category.posts
end
```

Comment: I tried this but i just got redirected to /posts/1 not /r/category/posts/1

Comment: @Wesly how do you set your `@category` variable?

Comment: I don't have it set. You did say that I should indicate to which category variable the @category is set to. How should it be?